# SPD - PageLayout set name in tag PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue

Tags: content-type, page-layout, spfield

I have two templates for pageLayout and use two fields from some content type. Can u set another name in this tag ??

```
<!--MS:<PageFieldDateTimeField:DateTimeField FieldName="8336201e-40ba-494c-95b7-42d9096709f6" runat="server">-->
    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)-->

    <!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
<!--ME:</PageFieldDateTimeField:DateTimeField>-->
```

I want to use the same field but with another name.

Comment: A single field can only be used once in a page layout, otherwise the values will overwrite each other

Answer (score 0):

the FieldName is a name of ref to field

you can set differant id for Every one of them, (id attribute is only for you)